# Where does the ability to do magic derive from in the Harry Potter universe: the body, soul, or some other entity?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory

If magic comes from the body, then how does Voldemort retain his magical abilities when he is regenerated? The potion used to regenerate his body involves the bones of his father, the flesh of Wormtail, and the blood of Harry. However, Voldemort's power came from his mother's side, and none of these have genetic material from her. If magical ability comes from the soul, then Voldemort would surely become weaker after dividing his soul into seven pieces, but this is not the case. Regarding the argument that the soul is like a candle in the sense that it has regenerative capabilities, Voldemort shriveled up soul in Kings Cross Station is evidence enough that this is untrue. So which is it: body, soul, or something else?

Comment: No canon source so I guess is from consciousness of wizard

Comment: Midichlorians?  (d+r)